# How to check for missing rows and incorrect data in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a table of hourly dating spanning a few years. I would like to find if it’s missing an hour or not. Is there an easy way to do this without lopping through the data row by row?

In addition, if the numbers in some of the values are > than XXX I would like to take the average of the entry before and after. Is this possible?

Thank you!

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19599227/edit) your question to address the following: **(1)** Please create one question per issue. Two questions should be two *separate* questions. **(2)** Please provide representative samples of your data and your desired results. Don't make us guess. **(3)** "Is is possible?" is usually not a valid question. Tell us *what you have tried* (or, at the very least, *what you are considering trying*).

Answer (score 0):

For the missing hours, how about something like this, assuming the source table is called Source and it has an integral field called Hour:

```
SELECT DISTINCT HourPlusOne AS MissingHour
FROM
  ( SELECT Hour + 1 AS HourPlusOne
    FROM Source
    WHERE Hour < (SELECT Max(Hour) FROM Source) ) AS PlusOnes
  LEFT JOIN Source ON PlusOnes.HourPlusOne = Source.Hour
WHERE Hour Is Null
ORDER BY HourPlusOne;
```